# ASP NET MVC VB if searchstring is empty do or else LINQ

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq

```
Function Index(SearchString As String, page As Integer?) As ActionResult
        If page Is Nothing Then
            page = 1
        Else
            page = page
        End If
        Dim List = (From m In db.maintenances Where (m.description OrElse m.description.Contains(SearchString)))

        Dim pagesize = 25
        Dim pageNumber As Integer = (If(page, 1))
        Return View(List.OrderBy(Function(o) o.id).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pagesize))
    End Function
```

Now i have this piece of code in my controller

what i would like to do if searchstring is empty return all results but if its not empty filter those that contain the searchstring how can i make this so i dont have to write multple queries to filter out the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the `Where` clause only if it is required. Instead of

```
Dim List = (From m In db.maintenances Where (m.description OrElse m.description.Contains(SearchString)))
```

you change to Linq extension method syntax and add the `Where` clause only if it is required:

```
Dim List = db.maintenances.AsQueryable()
If Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(SearchString) Then
    List = List.Where(Function(x) m.description IsNot Nothing AndAlso m.description.Contains(SearchString))
End If
```

The query will only be executed at the end of your method when you call `ToPagedList`, so all the records are only retrieved if there is no search clause.

If you need to add another condition, just add another `Where` clause, for example:

```
Dim List = db.maintenances.AsQueryable()
If Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(SearchString) Then
    List = List.Where(Function(x) m.description IsNot Nothing AndAlso m.description.Contains(SearchString))
End If
If selectedBranchId IsNot Nothing Then
    List = List.Where(Function(x) m.branch_id = selectedBranchId)
End If
```

Comment: For some reason its returning this error
{"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Test.' to data type bit."}

Comment: @JohnTrumpe I think the error is in the part `m.description OrElse ` that I have taken from your sample. I will update my answer.

Comment: One more question i would also like to add a branch_id to the filter which is an integer how would i go about this using your example?

Comment: Any ideas? for this?

Comment: @JohnTrumpe: would the branch id also be used if there is no search term? Basically you can integrate it in the `Where` clause as appropriate.

Comment: im making an advanced filter so yes each individual variable should be filterable

Comment: ive tried the following  returnview = returnview.Where(Function(m) m.branch_id AndAlso m.branch_id.Equals(Vestiging)) this however gave me an error

Comment: If there are any other methods for accomplishing an advanced filter please let me know

Comment: @JohnTrumpe I've updated the answer. Does this help?

Comment: Yes this does work :) didnt know you could chain where statements like that thanks:)